# How do I access the iteration counter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In Ruby on Rails, how can I access the iteration counter within a loop?

The following works, but using the `child_number` variable is a bit of a hack. Is there a better way of achieving this?

```
<% 5.times { @parent.child.build } %>

<%= form_for @parent do |parent_form| %>
  <p>
    <%= parent_form.label :full_name, "Parent's name" %>
    <%= parent_form.text_field :full_name %>
  </p>

  <%= parent_form.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
    <% @child_number ||= 1 %>
    <p>
      <%= child_form.label :full_name, "Child #{@child_number}'s name" %>
      <%= child_form.text_field :full_name %>
    </p>
    <% @child_number += 1 %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= parent_form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. I believe you're interested in accessing the iteration counter inside the parent_form.fields_for loopp, but that isn't immediately evident.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it'll be in the Rails 3.2 - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/1189

> ...I will assign it to 3.2 milestone...

It'll be look like https://github.com/jmbejar/rails/commit/7c562d5e460d97b18e4f3367b3cfb13401732920

Now you can use something like that:

```
<% 5.times { @parent.child.build } %>

<%= form_for @parent do |parent_form| %>
  ...
  <%= parent_form.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= child_form.label :full_name, "Child #{child_form.object_name.gsub(/[^0-9]+/,'')}'s name" %>
      <%= child_form.text_field :full_name %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

This just index the association:

```
<% 5.times do {@parent.children.build } %> 
#should be in your controller

    <%= form_for @parent do |parent_form| %>
        <%= parent_form.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
            This will return the index
            <%= parent_form.object.children.index(child_form.object) %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Make sure I got the associations right but the logic is good.

Comment: I though you could figure the rest out sorry.

Comment: -1 This will create 5 forms. Each with progressively more children. P.S. nash isn't the OP

Answer (score -1):

Use Enumerable **each_with_index**

```
       ().each_with_index do |elem,i|
        end
```